# how do show alert message on form submit in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" class="form-group" action="/registeruserdetails" method="post"
    onsubmit="registeredSuccesfull()">
        <h2 style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:25px">User Registration Form</h2>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                            <% if (repeatemail) { %>
                                <div class="toast" id="myToast">
                                    <div class="toast-body text-danger">
                                        A User with this email already exists
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <% } %>
                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="inputname">First name </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required
                pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]$" title="Name should only contain Letters e.g. John">
            </div
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="email">Email </label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email" required
                    pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
                    title=" Enter an Valid Email Address e.g example@gmail.com">
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="password">Password </label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                    pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}"
                    title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and contain atleast 8 to 16  characters"
                    required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 d-flex">
                <label for="gender mt-2">Gender:</label>

                <div class="mt-1  ms-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male" required>

                    <label for="male" class="radio-inline">Male</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female" required>
                    <label for="female" class="radio-inline">Female</label>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12 mt-2 text-center m-2">
                    <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                   


            </div>
```

how do i show alert if the registration is successfull

i tried writing if else but didnt help im new to ejs

Answer (score 0):

```html
<% if (repeatemail) { %>
  <!-- your html -->
<% } else { %>
  <!-- your html -->
<% } %>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: ejs is a server side template language. I don't know if you want build and show the message on the server or with js on client side